# How does the multicast worked in below code?

Tags: java

The following program prints unexpected output, can anyone please tell me how the multicast worked here. I searched a lot and got this typecast rule "Sign extension is performed if the type of the original value is signed; zero extension if it is a char, regardless of the type to which it is being
converted." Still unable to figure out the what happened while casting.

```
    public class Multicast 
    {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
          System.out.println((int) (char) (byte) -1);
       }
    }
```

Output: 65535

Comment: Well, `char` is unsigned, so the cast from char to int doesn't sign extend.  Thus you get the maximum value of a char.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @markspace thanks for your reply, i got this explanation, not sure how it worked.
"Because byte is a signed type, sign extension occurs when converting the byte value –1 to a char. The
resulting char value has all 16 bits set, so it is equal to 2^16 – 1, or 65,535. The cast from char to int is also a
widening primitive conversion, so the rule tells us that zero extension is performed rather than sign extension.
The resulting int value is 65535, which is just what the program prints."